# Swift - How can I pass a function with parameters in parameters of a function?

Tags: function, parameters, swift

I know that the title sounds complicated, but the question is not.

I have this Swift code:

```
class MyClass {
let helloWorld: (check: Bool)->()

init(helloWorld: (check: Bool)->()) {
    self.helloWorld = helloWorld
    }
}

let instanceOfMyClass = MyClass(helloWorld: (check: Bool) -> {

})
```

This gives me an error. What is the correct syntax for the last instruction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
let instanceOfMyClass = MyClass(helloWorld: { (check) in println(check) } )
```

but if the closure is the last argument, you can use the *[trailing closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_121)* syntax, where the closure is written outside of the function (init in your case) parenthesis - which is easier to read:

```
let instance = MyClass() { (check) in
    println(check)
}
```

There are other shortcuts to define closures, such as this one:

```
let instance2 = MyClass() { println($0) }
```

but I suggest you to read the entire [closure chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_112) in the official swift book.

*Note: in my code above replace `println(...)` with your actual processing*

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for the link too. I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to know my answer helped you ;-)

Comment: when there are no more parameters after taking out the closure, you can omit the parentheses: `MyClass { println($0) }`